# How to add new tabs in a web browser on Android

Tags: android

I am building a web browser for Android but I don't know how to go about adding new tabs to the browser. For example when you click new tab on chrome a new tab is added . Please how can I implement this in my own browser

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the traditional tabs (as per material design [Tabs](https://material.io/components/tabs/android) you can use a `TabLayout`, which provides a way to display tabs horizontally. When used together with a `ViewPager`, a `TabLayout` can provide a familiar interface for navigating between pages in a swipe view.

See implementation details [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-swipe-view)

Chrome mini-windows are a custom widget, so if you want that you need to implement it yourself.